# Select case class based on String in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How can I select a `case class` based on a `String` value?

My code is

```scala
val spark = SparkSession.builder()...
val rddOfJsonStrings: RDD[String] = // some json strings as RDD
val classSelector: String = ??? // could be "Foo" or "Bar", or any other String value
case class Foo(foo: String)
case class Bar(bar: String)


if (classSelector == "Foo") {
  val df: DataFrame = spark.read.json(rddOfJsonStrings)
  df.as[Foo]
} else if (classSelector == "Bar") {
  val df: DataFrame = spark.read.json(rddOfJsonStrings)
  df.as[Bar]
} else {
  throw ClassUnknownException //custom Exception
}
```

The variable `classSeletector` is a simple String that should be used to point to the case class of the same name.

Imagine I don't only have `Foo` and `Bar` as case classes but more then those two. How is it possible to call the `df.as[]` statement based on the String (if possible at all)?

Or is there a completely different approach available in Scala?

Comment: can you explain - classSelector & is it function ?

Comment: the classSelector is a simple String that is given e.g. through the main(args) function. Is it possible to use the value of this string to point to the case class with the identical name?

Comment: means something like classSelector="Foo" ??

Comment: The "completely different approach" would be to use a *typeclass* that encapsulates the specific behaviour for `Foo` and `Bar`. There are various tutorials about this online, so pick one that looks right for you.

Comment: @mike Note: I've edited the answer because it turns out it's much easier to do partially than I thought, writing so you'll get a notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How is it possible to call the df.as[] statement based on the String (if possible at all)?

It isn't (or based on any runtime value). You may note that all answers still need to:

1. have a separate branch for `Foo` and `Bar` (and one more branch for each class you'll want to add);
2. repeat the class name twice in the branch.

You can avoid the second:

```
import scala.reflect.{classTag, ClassTag}

val df: DataFrame = spark.read.json(rddOfJsonStrings)
// local function defined where df and classSelector are visible
def dfAsOption[T : Encoder : ClassTag] =
  Option.when(classSelector == classTag[T].runtimeClass.simpleName)(df.as[T])

dfAsOption[Foo].dfAsOption(asOption[Bar]).getOrElse(throw ClassUnknownException)
```

But for the first you'd need a macro if it's possible at all. I would guess it isn't.

Answer (score 2):

Check below code

```
classSeletector match {
    case c if Foo.getClass.getSimpleName.replace("$","").equalsIgnoreCase(c) =>  spark.read.json(rddOfJsonStrings).as[Foo]
    case c if Bar.getClass.getSimpleName.replace("$","").equalsIgnoreCase(c) =>  spark.read.json(rddOfJsonStrings).as[Bar]
    case _ => throw ClassUnknownException //custom Exception
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a generic method and invoke it,

```
getDs[Foo](spark,rddOfJsonStrings)
getDs[Bar](spark,rddOfJsonStrings)

def getDs[T](spark : SparkSession, rddOfJsonStrings:String)  {
    spark.read.json(rddOfJsonStrings).as[T](Encoders.bean[T](classOf[T]))
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply @QuickSilver. If I understand correctly, this will reduce a bit of code, but how could I use the content of `classSelector` to avoid calling `getDs[Foo]` and `getDs[Bar]` individually. I was hoping to do something like `getDs[classSelector.asClassName]`.

Answer (score 0):

### Alternative-

**highlights-**

1. Use `simpleName` of the case class and not of the companion object
2. if `classSelector` is `null`, the solution won't fail

```scala
case class Foo(foo: String)
case class Bar(bar: String)
```

### Testcase-

```scala
 val rddOfJsonStrings: RDD[String] = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq("""{"foo":1}"""))
    val classSelector: String = "Foo" // could be "Foo" or "Bar", or any other String value

    val ds = classSelector match {
      case foo if classOf[Foo].getSimpleName == foo =>
        val df: DataFrame = spark.read.json(rddOfJsonStrings)
        df.as[Foo]
      case bar if classOf[Bar].getSimpleName == bar =>
        val df: DataFrame = spark.read.json(rddOfJsonStrings)
        df.as[Bar]
      case _ => throw new UnsupportedOperationException
    }

    ds.show(false)

    /**
      * +---+
      * |foo|
      * +---+
      * |1  |
      * +---+
      */
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [reflective toolbox](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/symbols-trees-types.html#tree-creation-via-parse-on-toolboxes)

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Dataset, SparkSession}
import scala.reflect.runtime
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox

object Main extends App {
  val spark = SparkSession.builder
    .master("local")
    .appName("Spark SQL basic example")
    .getOrCreate()
  import spark.implicits._

  val rddOfJsonStrings: Dataset[String] = spark.createDataset(Seq("""{"foo":"aaa"}"""))
  // val rddOfJsonStrings: Dataset[String] = spark.createDataset(Seq("""{"bar":"bbb"}"""))

  val classSelector: String = "Foo"
  // val classSelector: String = "Bar"

  case class Foo(foo: String)
  case class Bar(bar: String)

  val runtimeMirror = runtime.currentMirror
  val toolbox = runtimeMirror.mkToolBox()

  val res = toolbox.eval(toolbox.parse(s"""
    import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
    import Main._
    import spark.implicits._
    val df: DataFrame = spark.read.json(rddOfJsonStrings)
    df.as[$classSelector]
  """)).asInstanceOf[Dataset[_]]

  println(res) // [foo: string]
}
```

Notice that statically you will have a `Dataset[_]`, not `Dataset[Foo]` or `Dataset[Bar].`