# How to infer StructType schema for Spark Scala at run time given a Fully Qualified Name of a case class

Tags: scala, apache-spark, reflection, configuration, schema

Since a few days I was wondering if it is possible to infer a schema for Spark in Scala for a given case class, but unknown at compile time.

The only input is a string containing the FQN of the class (that could be used for example to create an instance of the case class at runtime via reflection)

I was thinking if it was possible to do something like:

```scala
package com.my.namespace

case class MyCaseClass (name: String, num: Int)

//Somewhere else in codebase

// coming from external configuration file, so unknown at compile time
val fqn = "com.my.namespace.MyCaseClass" 


val schema = Encoders.product [ getXYZ( fqn ) ].schema
```

Of course, any other techniques that is not using `Encoders` is fine (building `StructType` analysing an instance of the case class ? Is it even possible ?)

What is the best approach?
Is it something feasible ?

Comment: I asked a similar question in [Select Case Class based on String in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62283312/select-case-class-based-on-string-in-scala)

Comment: You can't invoke it in a standard way, but you could pattern match on the FQN and use that to make the proper `Encoders.product[X]` call. Either that or macros.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Yes, that is a possibility but pattern matching means that it must be known at compile time, so you cannot write a library that is extensible (considering what is in the class path for example) as you can do for example if reflection can be used.

I am interested in the macro approach, but I cannot really understand how that could be used..

Comment: @btbbass Definitely, I was assuming types are known at compile time. If not, reflections shenanigans are unavoidable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [reflective toolbox](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/symbols-trees-types.html#tree-creation-via-parse-on-toolboxes)

```
package com.my.namespace

import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType
import scala.reflect.runtime
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox

case class MyCaseClass (name: String, num: Int)

object Main extends App {

  val fqn = "com.my.namespace.MyCaseClass" 

  val runtimeMirror = runtime.currentMirror
  val toolbox = runtimeMirror.mkToolBox()

  val res = toolbox.eval(toolbox.parse(s"""
    import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders
    Encoders.product[$fqn].schema
  """)).asInstanceOf[StructType]

  println(res) // StructType(StructField(name,StringType,true),StructField(num,IntegerType,false))
}
```

Comment: Simply awesome! Tested with Spark 3.x, it works.

Thanks a lot